# curl - upload filename with spaces using --form

Tags: curl

We're currently uploading files using cURL, with the following command:

```sh
curl -X POST <url> --form file=@original.pdf;filename=override.pdf
```

which all works well. However, we're stuck on how to specify the `filename` option when it includes spaces. We've tried:

```
filename="override with spaces.pdf"
filename=\"override with spaces.pdf"
filename=override%20with%20spaces.pdf
filename=override+with+spaces.pdf
```

The first two give the following warning:

```
Warning: config-broken:3: warning: '--form' uses unquoted white space in the
Warning: line that may cause side-effects!
```

Is there a format/escape pattern that will allow uploads with spaces? Or does it require some configuration changes on the server side to allow this to be imported (we're running an ASP.NET Core API).

Comment: you did mean `filename=\"blah\"` , didn't you? I would try `fname="name%20withSpaces"`. Also indicate what is the "wrapper" environment for executing this cmd, `bash`, `sh`, php, python, etc? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `--form "file=@original.pdf;filename=something else.pdf"` is correct and produces the desired result.